# SD Card No Memory

Tags: raspbian, raspbmc, sd-card

I bought a Raspberry Pi Starter kit online (and it came with a sd card), and had it running Raspbian.  I then went and installed Rasbmc on it and I corrupted my SD Card.  I wiped it clear and then installed Noobs on it and ran Rasbmc.  I wanted to go back and install Raspbian on it again but it said I did not have enough memory.  I wiped it AGAIN and installed noobs, plugged it into my raspberry pi and it said I did not have enough memory still.  Since then, I have tried formatting it several times but I cannot get it to clear.  I am trying to do this from a Mac.

Comment: type `sudo parted` then `print` at the Pi prompt, then post the result.

Comment: Open `Disk Utility`. Select your SD card on the left. Open the tab Partition on the right. Change `Partition Layout` to `1 Partition.

Comment: I am loading raspbmc to show the result of sudo parted...@Milliways  I will then try @Gerben 's idea.

Comment: Update: @milliways I tried the sudo parted and got the command not found.  I am sure I spelled it the same as you did.

Comment: It is possible the partition manager is not in RaspBMC. You could use `Disk Utility` or `diskutil list` on the Mac to list partitions, but this will not show Ext4. You could use @Gerben's suggestion to erase the card, but this is not necessary if you are copying a fresh NOOBS using `du` or similar.

Comment: @milliways is that going to get me more memory?  That is my end goal.  I had enough before but for some reason I am not able to use the memory

Comment: This is a diagnostic to help determine your problem. You have given almost no information - the size of the SD card, what the current usage is, how you tried installation. In fact I think NOOBS just makes it harder. I wastes a lot of the card with images most users never use, and complicates the setup process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment so I'll have to post this as an answer. What size is your SD card? Somewhere I read that the latest versions of Raspbian require 4GB+. I have found that NOOBS often requires a bigger size because it has an installer and then also has the operating system you want to use (Raspbian, OpenELEC, RaspBMC etc etc).

Comment: I think your right.  I just found a 8GB SD card and I put NOOBS on it.  It worked.  The thing I was trying to figure out is why it let me use the first one before  but not now.  Maybe it's the two additional programs that were added to Raspbian - mathematis and wolfram

Comment: Quite possibly, although they'd be quite small :)

Comment: It told me I needed like 10 megabytes more, so that was probably it.

Comment: I think wolfram and dependencies are on the order of 500 MB...why Raspbian includes it by default I do not understand.

Comment: @goldilocks yeah so maybe not quite so small...

Answer (score 0):

NOOBS require atleast of 4GB memory. So we need atleast 8GB memory card for it's installation. I think you got 4GB SD Card. That's why it shows it doesn't have enough memory to carried out installation.